# cakephp set current named params in redirecting link

Tags: url, cakephp, parameters

I want to redirect to index action along with all current `named params` (`$this->params['named']`), I tried many thing but it is not working.

tried the following

```
$params = '';
foreach($this->params['named'] as $k=>$v){
       $params = $params."'".$k.':'.$v.'\',';
}

//-also tried
$params = array();
foreach($this->params['named'] as $k=>$v){
       $params[$k] = $k.':'.$v;
}
$params = implode(',',$params);



echo $this->Html->link('list friends',
       array('controller'=>'friends','action'=>'index',$params)
       );
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

Comment: I can't find any method which get all named parameters and send to new page, in this page 1 by 1 param is explained, not how to send dynamic params naming differently in different situations. if you can get any solution please post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->link('list friends',
    array('controller'=>'friends','action'=>'index') + $this->params['named']
);
```

If you want to combine two arrays together you can use the + operator between both arrays